# Calling Methods Error

Tags: java, methods

I keep getting the error cannot find symbol. Symbol: Method countAll. However, how i have it set up my professor keeps insisting this is how to have it set up.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java. util.*;
public class Homework15{
  public static void main(String args[]){
     try {
      JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
      chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
      File text = chooser.getSelectedFile();
      LetterCount.countAll(text);
      }
    catch (IOException error) {
      System.out.println(error);
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: What is LetterCount? Your current class doesn't know what class LetterCount is in this context. If you want to use it statically it should be declared as so.

Comment: Maybe using an IDE like Eclipse gives you the information you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using a static method called `countAll` from the class `LetterCount`, you need to import such class, like this:

`import your.package.LetterCount;`

where `your.package` is the [package where that class is located](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html)

Answer (score 0):

`LetterCount` sounds like a utility class with static methods inside so you probably haven't imported the correct packages on top from from it looks like. Go to the class and on top copy the package path and import it in the class with the main method.

Also make sure that the methods are actually static.

Answer (score 0):

As Juxhin and Jmm said: make sure to import the packages. If that doesn't work make sure your countAll method is not private. Because if it is private you won't be able to access it outside of the LetterCount class.